# Classes interacting with Tomcat servlets

Tags: android, tomcat, servlets

I want to create a game which goes back and fourth to the servlet and acts when the user clicks a button. So the logic will be within a servlet and this logic will be called from an android class.

Not sure how to go about this, please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a REST + JSON service on your server: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html
2. Create a REST client on Android: http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/

There are many more REST examples on the web for server and Android clients.